# Raspberry pi proximity detection nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a motion and proximity sensor hooked up to the raspberry pi. What I want to happen is when the motion sensor detects a motion, it gets a reading from the proximity sensor to see how close the person is...once the person gets within a certain distance, a message is displayed.

The motion sensor is being triggered and I am getting a reading from the proximity sensor, however, the proximity sensor gets caught in a loop and the value doesn't ever update (even when there is someone right on top of it).

motion :

```
import gpio from 'gpio';
import proximity from './proximity';

const gpio4 = gpio.export(4, {
  direction: 'in',
});

// bind to the "change" event
gpio4.on('change', (val) => {
  // value will report either 1 or 0 (number) when the value changes
  if (val === 1) {
    console.log('checking proximity');
    proximity.getDistance();
  }
});
```

proximity :

```
import gpio from 'gpio';

// pin 38 GPIO 20 - for trigger
const trig = gpio.export(38, {
  direction: 'out'
});

// pin 37 GPIO 26 - for echo
const echo = gpio.export(37, {
  direction: 'in'
});

function getDistance() {
  const speedSound = 34000;
  // resetting trigger
  trig.set(0);
  setTimeout(500);
  console.log("initial trig value (0): " + trig.value); // should be 0
  responsiveVoice.speak('');
  const timestamp = moment().add(30, 's');
  let start = 0;
  let end = 0;

  trig.set();
  setTimeout(10);
  trig.set(0);

  while (echo.value === 0) {
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log('Echo is ' + echo.value);
  }

  while (echo.value === 1) {
    end = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log('Echo is ' + echo.value);
    let timeDiff = end - start;
    let distance = (timeDiff * speedSound) / 2;

    console.log('Distance = ' + distance);

    if (distance < 60) {
      console.log('User is within 2 ft. Enable voice');
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getDistance
};
```

What do I need to do to get this working correctly without getting stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: What is echo.value? I'm sure you're stuck in one of those while loops. How does echo.value change from 0 to 1 and vice versa?

Comment: @HamiltonLucas if the proximity sensor detects something the echo.value = 1, if not then it's 0. I've been basing the code off of this python code : http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/12/ultrasonic-distance-measurement-using-python-part-1/ if i start with nothing in front of the sensor i get echo.value = 0 and it gets stuck in that loop even when I move something infront of it, vice versa if i start with something in front of it i get echo.value = 1 and when i move it away from the sensor it still is stuck in that loop

Comment: For starters, this does not do anything useful and probably not what you want: `setTimeout(500);`.  That does not wait 500ms before proceeding.  In fact, it does nothing.  The first argument for `setTimeout()` is a function that will be called sometime in the future.  The second argument is a time to wait before calling that function.   The next line of code after the `setTimeout()` executes immediately.  It does not wait for the timeout value.

Comment: You cannot do a while loop expecting some other  code to run and change the variable you are testing.  Javascript is single threaded and as long as you are in the while loop, NO other code will run so your variable will never change and thus you have an infinite loop.  Instead, you should either use a natively triggered event or use `setInterval()` to poll the value every once in a while (it depends upon how your proximity interface works).

Comment: I agree with jfriend00 - the value of "echo.value" never changes, because the single javascript thread is too busy iterating through your while loop to be able to run the sensor. Rather than using a while loop, you should probably define a function that calls itself recursively using setTimeout so that the thread has time to go do other work (such as set the value of echo.value) in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a while loop expecting some other code to run and change the variable you are testing. Javascript is single threaded and as long as you are in the while loop, NO other code will run so your variable will never change and thus you have an infinite loop.

So, something like this:

```
while (echo.value === 0) {
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log('Echo is ' + echo.value);
}
```

is an infinite loop if `echo.value` ever starts out `=== 0`.  As long as that `while` loop is running, `echo.value` can never get its value changed - thus it ends up an infinite loop.  This is the nature of the single threadedness and the event driven nature.

Javascript is an event driven language.  The current thread of execution runs until completion and then (and only then) does the JS engine pull the next event from the event queue and run the code associated with that event.  Thus, `while` loops waiting for some external code to change some variable never work in Javascript because that external code can never run as long as the `while` loop is running.

Instead, you should either use a natively triggered event or use `setInterval()` to poll the value every once in a while (it depends upon how your proximity interface works).

---

In addition, a line of code like this:

```
setTimeout(500);
```

does absolutely nothing.  First off, `setTimeout()` expects two arguments.  The first should be a function to call at some time in the future.  The second argument should be a time value in ms.  And, `setTimeout()` does not pause execution at all.  All it does is schedule a timer to fire some time in the future and then it immediately executes the next line of code.  There is no waiting in Javascript.  Instead, you schedule some callback to run sometime in the future.

---

The right solution here depends upon how your proximity sensor interface works (something that is not fully described in your question).  If it is, itself, event driven (which would be ideal), then you can just subscribe to one of its events and each time that event fires, you can check the value and decide what action should be carried out.  This would not involve any timers or any looping.  You may want to save some state so when the next event fires you know what happened recently, but you don't go into loops or use timers if things are event driven.

If the interface is not event driven, then you may need to "poll" the state using a recurring `setInterval()` timer.  In that case, you pick some time interval (say every second) and you check the proximity value and then decide what action to take based on the value you see.   `setInterval()` works like this:

```
// poll once per second
setInterval(function() {
    // put some code here that will run every second
}, 1000);

// code here will run immediately - the timer callback runs some time in the future
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's getting stuck in the while loops, you can instead define a function that recursively calls itself every second (or whatever interval) to check the value of echo.

You just need to replace your while loops with something like what I've illustrated below.

```
while (echo.value === 0) {
  start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  console.log('Echo is ' + echo.value);
}

while (echo.value === 1) {
  end = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  console.log('Echo is ' + echo.value);
  let timeDiff = end - start;
  let distance = (timeDiff * speedSound) / 2;

  console.log('Distance = ' + distance);

  if (distance < 60) {
    console.log('User is within 2 ft. Enable voice');
    responsiveVoice.speak('Hello, I am Jarvis; welcome to Cardinal Solutions. Please check in.');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

becomes

```
function checkEchoValue() {
  if(echo.value === 0) {
    console.log("Echo value is zero.");
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  } else {
    console.log('Echo value is non-zero');

    end = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    let timeDiff = end - start;
    let distance = (timeDiff * speedSound) / 2;

    console.log('Distance = ' + distance);

    if (distance < 60) {
      console.log('User is within 2 ft. Enable voice');
      responsiveVoice.speak('Hello, I am Jarvis; welcome to Cardinal Solutions. Please check in.');
    }
  }

  setTimeout(checkEchoValue, 1000); 
  //calls this method again in a second
}
```

Make sure to call checkEchoValue() at least once when you actually want to start checking values (probably where your while loops are now.)